# TypeError: undefined is not an object 'createElement' of undefined - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `LoginForm.js` component

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardSection } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection />

                <CardSection />

                <CardSection>
                    <Button>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </CardSection>


            </Card>
        );
    }

}

export default LoginForm;
```

I tried to integrate it into my App.js like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

import { Header } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';


class App extends Component {


    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: '*********',
            authDomain: 'rn-auth-a3fb5.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://rn-auth-a3fb5.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'rn-auth-a3fb5',
            storageBucket: 'rn-auth-a3fb5.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '34567890'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText='Authentication' />
                <LoginForm />

            </View>

        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

I kept getting an error

[image]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined

> This error is located at:
>       in LoginForm (at App.js:26)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:32)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)

[image]

Which I expect to get something like this

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your React import in `LoginForm.js` is incorrect. `React` should be the default import.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```