# Configuring defaultNavigationOption headerBackImage throws undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Configuring the `defaultNavigationOptions` as such:

```
defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {},
    headerBackImage: <Image source={require('../assets/icons/back.png')}/>,
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerLeftContainerStyle: {},
    headerRightContainerStyle: {},
  }
```

within the createAppContainer method immediately throws

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.React.createElement')

The image is definitely at the correct location, and commenting out the `headerBackImage` property resolves the problem. Is this bugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check if you're correctly importing React as the default import

check the links below where other developers had the same issue as you and solved their problems by correcting this

[TypeError: undefined is not an object 'createElement' of undefined - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316781/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-createelement-of-undefined-react-nativ)

[TypeError : React object is undefined on createElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600763/typeerror-react-object-is-undefined-on-createelement)

let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: The problem was that I had `import { React } from 'react';` what fixed it was changing that to `import React from 'react';`Thank you.